# php javascript - add remove dynamic form (with datepicker input)

Tags: javascript, php, clone

i use some code to clone form elements but i dont know how it works with  with datepicker.

Can someone update the code that i can use datepicker by input what can be clone? With query ui?

```js
//define template
var template = $('#sections .section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;

        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);

        //update id
        this.id = newId;

    }).end()

    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#sections');
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('#sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
   <div id="sections">
  <div class="section">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>test form - <a href="#" class='button red remove'>delete</a></legend>
        <p>
            <label for="number1">number1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number1[]"/>
        </p>
  
  <p>
<label for="number2">number2:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number2[]"/>
        </p>
  
  <p>
            <label for="selcet1">selcet1:</label>
  <select name="select1[]" required>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
  </select>
        </p>

        <p>
<label for="selcet2">selcet2:</label>
        <select name="selcet2[]" required>
   <option value="1" >1</option>
      <option value="2" >2</option>
   </select>
        </p>


  <p>
<label for="date">Date:</label>
 <input type="text" name="date[]" required /> 
        </p>
  <p>
            <label for="text">text:</label>
<textarea rows=3 type="text" name="text[]" > </textarea>
        </p>

      
    </fieldset>
 
  </div>
</div>

       <a href="#" class='addsection'>add form</a>
```

I dont know how to add a datepicker by the 
// input type="text" name="date[]" required // that i can clone and use.

Please can someone help me that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JqueryUI solution

```js
//define template
var template = $('#sections .section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;

        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);

        //update id - THIS CAUSES JqueryUI Datepicker to bug, also you shouldn't use numerical only IDs
        //this.id = newId;

    }).end()

    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#sections');
    //initialize datePicker on last name=date[] element in HTML DOM
    $("input[name='date[]']").last().datepicker();
    return false;
});
//init original datePicker in HTML DOM
$("input[name='date[]']").last().datepicker();
//remove section
$('#sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   
   <div id="sections">
  <div class="section">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>test form - <a href="#" class='button red remove'>delete</a></legend>
        <p>
            <label for="number1">number1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number1[]"/>
        </p>
  
  <p>
<label for="number2">number2:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number2[]"/>
        </p>
  
  <p>
            <label for="selcet1">selcet1:</label>
  <select name="select1[]" required>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
  </select>
        </p>

        <p>
<label for="selcet2">selcet2:</label>
        <select name="selcet2[]" required>
   <option value="1" >1</option>
      <option value="2" >2</option>
   </select>
        </p>


  <p>
<label for="date">Date:</label>
 <input type="text" name="date[]" required /> 
        </p>
  <p>
            <label for="text">text:</label>
<textarea rows=3 type="text" name="text[]" > </textarea>
        </p>

      
    </fieldset>
 
  </div>
</div>

       <a href="#" class='addsection'>add form</a>
```

Comment: @Peisi Found a bug in your code... ID shouldn't be numerical only. Also setting ID for the datepicker causes bug even after initializing it, since DatePicker will set it's own ID. Now question is - do you need your own custom ID to distinct input fields? I'd suggest using input names instead.

Comment: I will use the form to Save the Inputs in mysql Database. I Can try it tomorrow at work. Java Script is Not easy for me. You mean i dont Need the id's for what i will do?

Comment: @Peisi it all comes to the question "How will you choose to do it" - if you use <form>, then the php $_POST["fieldName"] uses `input name`, to select values. If you choose to use ajax post - then you are pretty much free to choose how you will handle the data, that you will post. You can create javascript object/array and loop through all input elements, set the key based on input names etc... If all input field names are unique, you shouldn't have problems in both scenarios.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I will try your solution tomorrow at work and give you feedback

Comment: Hey @Adam K. your Solution works for me =) Thank you very much

Comment: @Peisi glad to hear that, please tick my answer as solution. I'd appreciate it... With rep over 50 i will finally be able to comment anywhere :)

Comment: @Peisi I don't want to spam you, but please tick the answer as solution. - Having rep below 50 is somewhat frustrating, when i can't ask for details in comments of original question and even when i'd need more information, i can interact only via answers.

Comment: hey @Adam K. ok now? i have tick =)

Comment: @Peisi Cheers mate. Happy coding best of luck :)

Comment: @AdamK. its possible add previous row data to dynamically generated row ? what part of code i can modify to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

### HTML5 DatePicker Solution

Native HTML5 datepicker is supported only in modern browsers and not even all of them.
Simply use `type="date"` instead of `type="text"`

---

If you want 100% working datepicker, you will have to look at `JqueryUI`.

If you want JqueryUI datepicker to work with cloned elements, you will have to initialize new date input fields as datepicker jquery input element after cloning them.

---

```js
//define template
var template = $('#sections .section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;

        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);

        //update id
        this.id = newId;

    }).end()

    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#sections');
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('#sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
   <div id="sections">
  <div class="section">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>test form - <a href="#" class='button red remove'>delete</a></legend>
        <p>
            <label for="number1">number1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number1[]"/>
        </p>
  
  <p>
<label for="number2">number2:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number2[]"/>
        </p>
  
  <p>
            <label for="selcet1">selcet1:</label>
  <select name="select1[]" required>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
  </select>
        </p>

        <p>
<label for="selcet2">selcet2:</label>
        <select name="selcet2[]" required>
   <option value="1" >1</option>
      <option value="2" >2</option>
   </select>
        </p>


  <p>
<label for="date">Date:</label>
 <input type="date" name="date[]" required /> 
        </p>
  <p>
            <label for="text">text:</label>
<textarea rows=3 type="text" name="text[]" > </textarea>
        </p>

      
    </fieldset>
 
  </div>
</div>

       <a href="#" class='addsection'>add form</a>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Can you Tell me how it works with query ui? In example by my code ?

Comment: @Peisi added JqueryUI solution

Comment: Hey my friend, i work with your solution. But now i found i bug for my insert into table code. Can you tell me why only the first and the last section of your code goíng into my mysql table? i work with "foreach $_POST as $value

Comment: Hello @Peisi - use Dev tools in Chrome to determine what do you really send from client. Then you can determine whether your error is on your client side or server side.

Chrome - Dev tools - network - document request - click - and discover headers values... If all data is sent - your problem is in your server code, if data is missing THEN:
Your inputs are dynamic - if you use a POST via javascript (not html form), then you have to loop through dynamic inputs at the moment you press the submit btn... My guess is that you init inputs on page load - leaving dynamic inputs lost. (My guesses)

Comment: In short - Determine whether you are *NOT PASSING* the data -or- *NOT PROCESSING* the data

Comment: Hey @Adam K. i have a new question to your solution =) Is it possible to clone the entry from input 1 and input 2 to next clone div section? Can you help to figure it out? =)

Comment: @Peisi you mean something like `var section = template.` changed to `var section = $('#sections .section:last-of-type').clone().` ?
just keep in mind, that you'll have to put there an if clause to use template, when there are no sections left.

Comment: Thanks @Adam K. , your solution works fine for me ^^